# Does Armor have a base +1 AC if made for tiny creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, armor-class

According to the [Armor for Unusual Creatures table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#armorForUnusualCreatures), tiny or smaller creatures receive half the AC from armor. So what happens to the armor bonus when the armor bonus is only +1?

For example, Gnome Twistcloth has +1 armor bonus when made for medium creatures. Does this armor still have a +1 armor bonus when made for tiny creatures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You round down unless stated otherwise. So it would have a +0 AC bonus. It could still exist as an armor if you wanted, and could be enhanced with a +1 (and thus have a +1 AC bonus overall). But Tiny versions of mundane +1 AC armor has no AC bonus.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8586/discussion-between-kryan-and-novian)

Comment: I forget, do size differences cause to-hit adjustments in 3.5? I might apply the full armour for tiny-on-tiny violence

Comment: @blueberryfields Every size category smaller than Medium results in a +1 Size bonus to attack and AC, a +4 Size bonus to Hide, and a -4 Size penalty to Grapple. These bonuses and penalties stack with each additional size category. Smaller creatures also have smaller Space and Reach.

Comment: Quite frankly, I would give armor at least a +1, otherwise I agree.